# awk regex for repeated character

Tags: regex, awk, nawk

I'm trying to match repeated patterns in strings. I know i can use `/^[0-9]{5}$/`
at least in perl, but this doesn't seem to work in awk or nawk (no gawk installed).

Any alternative, other than `/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/` ?

**EDIT:**

```
echo "AAB" > test
```

script.awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/nawk -f
BEGIN {}
/^A\{2,2\}/ { print "1"; }
/^A/ { print "2"; }
/A\{2,2\}/ { print "3"; }
/A{2,2}/ { print "4"; }
END {}

./script.awk test
```

only output (awk or nauk):

```
2
```

Comment: escape `{` and `}` using a backslash -> `/^[0-9]\{5\}$/`. This works for me with awk 4.1.1

Comment: What system are you using? The first syntax should be supported by `nawk`.

Comment: SunOS 5.10/Solaris 10, escaping { doesn't to it.

Comment: You can't use curly brackets without GNU awk, you also need to use `re-interval` with pre 4 releases. Look here http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_46.html

Comment: Thanks User112638726, that's what i was half-expecting. Answer it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default awk on Solaris is old, broken awk which should never be used by anyone for any reason. nawk is much better than /usr/bin/awk but is still a very old, non-POSIX awk, and so does not support RE intervals. Almost any other awk will work. On Solaris if you don't have and can't install GNU awk then use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk as it's very close to POSIX compliant and does support RE intervals.